# How do I keep a div in the center of the page?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm using jQuery to create a "dialog" that should pop up on top of the page and in the center of the page (vertically and horizontally). How should I go about making it stay in the center of the page (even when the user resizes or scrolls?)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I would use

```
position: fixed;
top: 50%;
left: 50%;
margin-left: -(dialogwidth/2);
margin-top: -(dialogheight/2);
```

but with this solution and a browsers viewport-size of less than your dialog is, parts of the dialog will be unreachable on top and left sides because they are outside the viewport.
So you have to decide if it's suitable for your dialogs size.

(CSS doesn't know how to calculate, yet. So the little math over there has to be done by you, right now. Therefore your dialog has to be a fixed size which you have to know.)

Edit:

Oh yes, if you want to serve your dialog for the IE6 too, you should do something like this:

```
#dialog { position: absolute; }
#dialog[id] { position: fixed; }
```

Since IE6 is not capable of fixed positions and also not capable of attribute-selectors, the IE6 will be the only one who has the position set to absolute. (This will only affect with scrolling behaviour. absolute stays on its place in page and fixed stays on its place in the browser. The rest is similar.)

Comment: Doesn't position fixed cause problems in IE6?

Answer (score 3):

Check out [Infinity Web Design's](http://www.infinitywebdesign.com/research/cssverticalcentereddiv.htm) piece on this.

```
#mydiv {
   background-color:#F3F3F3;
   border:1px solid #CCCCCC;
   height:18em;
   left:50%;
   margin-left:-15em;
   margin-top:-9em;
   position:absolute;
   top:50%;
   width:30em;
}
```

This is the CSS they use, and I've tested it out in multiple browsers.

You'll note that the left margin is negative half the width and the top margin is negative half the height. This takes care of the centering, more or less, with absolutely positioning it at 50% top and left.

Answer (score 0):

To put a div horizontally in the middle I always put margin: 0 auto. But it cannot be a floating element and in IE I always needed to put a div around and then give it the property text-align: center, so that the inside div is centered horizontally.

Answer (score 0):

If you know the element's offset dimensions (width/height + padding), you can use this CSS:

```
elementContainerSelector {
    position: fixed; /* You'll of course need to handle browsers that don't support fixed positioning */
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}

elementSelector {
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    margin: -[half of offset height]px 0 0 -[half of offset width]px;
}
```

Hurix's answer works too, and bear in mind the caveats in that answer as well.

Answer (score 0):

Keep margin-left:auto and margin-right:auto